# Proving $\cos \theta = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right)$ for all $\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

By drawing a right triangle it is obvious that $\cos \theta = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right)$. I'm trying to prove to myself that this is true for all values of $\theta$ by following the reasoning on [this page](http://people.hofstra.edu/stefan_Waner/realworld/trig/trig2.html) where the sine graph is inverted vertically by plugging in $-\theta$ and then shifted to the right by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get the cosine graph. To shift a graph to the right by $x$, don't you have to **subtract $x$ from the input value**?

I'm getting $\cos \theta = \sin\left(-\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ which is of course wrong and Wolfram shows me is the vertically-inverted cosine graph.

I know this is ridiculously simple and something to do with the $-\theta$ parameter to $\sin$ meaning that a right shift then needs the shift value added, but I can't see clearly why.

Comment: If you compose $f$ with $x\rightarrow x+T, T>0$, you shift its graph to the left, because lower values of x are (almost?) universally put on the left. You may check that on a graphing software -like Wolfram Alpha which is what you probably meant.

Comment: On the page you link to the author forgets to mention that putting the graph upside down is only replacing $t$ with $-t$ for the sine function because it is an odd function $sin(-t)=-sin(t)$. In general this does not hold, you invert the graph sending $f$ to $-f$ (not $t$), in particular $cos(-t)=cos(t)$, which allows to have the "symmetric" formulas $sin(t)=cos(\pi/2-t)$, $cos(t)=sin(\pi/2-t)$.

Comment: I looked at your profile, being a CAD developer I now guess you rather meant Mathematica, rather than Wolfram Alpha, sorry.

Comment: @plm: I did mean Wolfram Alpha, sorry for confusion. We don't have anything like Mathematica or MATLAB here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ denote the graph of the function $f$, hence $\gamma=\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$. Let $a$ denote a real number and $\alpha=(a,0)$. The set $\gamma+\alpha$ is
$$
\gamma+\alpha=\{u+\alpha\mid u\in\gamma\}=\{(x+a,f(x))\mid x\in\mathbb R\}=\{(t,f(t-a))\mid t\in\mathbb R\},
$$
hence
$\gamma+\alpha$ is the graph of the function $f_a:x\mapsto f(x-a)$.

In the present case, $f(x)=-\sin(x)$, $a=+\pi/2$ (remember the shift is to the right hence $a\gt0$), hence $f_a(x)=-\sin(x-\pi/2)=\sin(\pi/2-x)$, as desired.

Comment: I'm trying to go through this step by step. Am I right in saying $\gamma$ is a set of ordered pairs? If so, what does it mean to say $u + a$ where $u\in\gamma$? Looks like this is adding a to the first element of $u$, right?

Comment: You can probably ignore my comment as I guess the answer is you've provided the definition of addition of a member of $\gamma$ and a real number (to be the first element of the ordered pair added with the real number). I've gone through your answer and it makes sense to me now. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent remark, I was sloppy. See revised version.

Comment: Appreciate the response and edit.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, one can use

$$\sin (a-b)=\sin a \cos b - \sin b \cos a$$

Then $a=\pi/2$ and $b=\theta$,

$$\sin (\pi/2-\theta)=\sin \pi/2 \cos \theta - \sin \theta \cos \pi/2$$

$$\sin (\pi/2-\theta)=1 \cdot \cos \theta - \sin \theta \cdot0$$

$$\sin (\pi/2-\theta)=\cos \theta $$

Comment: I like this other way of looking at it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Proofs are already given so I'm not giving a mathematical proof. **Indeed this is not a mathematical proof because from here you can only conclude that $\sin(\frac\pi2-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta<\frac\pi2$**.

[image]

**Consider the above figure**

$\sin(\frac \pi2-\theta)=\frac ah$ and $\cos(\theta)=\frac ah$

$\therefore \sin(\frac\pi2-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

Beware that you compose $sin$ *first* with $t\rightarrow -t$ and *then* the resulting function with the right-shift $t-\frac{\pi}{2}$, so you get the desired $cos(t)=sin(-(t-\frac{\pi}{2}))=sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)$.